# Merge multiple ObservableList into one List

Tags: java, javafx-8

How can I convert multiple Observablelist into one List? I need to join multiple tableview data into one list, so I needt to collect all rows into one list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just do

```
List<Whatever> concatenated = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(list, observableList1);
Collections.addAll(list, observableList2);
```

Since `ObservableList<T>` implements `List<T>`, you can pass ObservableLists to methods that take Lists as parameters.